# Pull all values from one table of non-distinct IDs to new table of Distinct IDs and Concatenate them all

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables: One of distinct IDs and another of non-distinct IDs with values

[image: Example Desired Output]
I'd like to pull all values for that ID and concatenate them into the 'Send ID' table. In the above image, it shows the desired output. I currently also have a one to many relationship between the IDs.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this but it requiers som nested table functions. This code should do it:

```
Clicks_Table = 
SELECTCOLUMNS(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        GENERATE(
            'Send_ID_Table';
            var strln = PATHLENGTH(SUBSTITUTE([DesiredValue];",";"|"))

            return
            GENERATESERIES(
                1;
                strln;
                1
            )
        );
        "selected"; PATHITEM(SUBSTITUTE([DesiredValue]; ","; "|"); [Value])
    );
    "ID"; [ID];
    "Value"; [selected]
)
```

I'm sure there's a more efficient way of doing this. If you come across a better solution, please let me know.

Comment: Sorry if my explanation was a little poor - I think this calculation creates the Clicks Table. The Clicks Table is already made. I need the Desired Value column in the Send ID table. (essentially the reverse of this)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorry for my misunderstanding. This code will take 'Clicks Table' and convert it into 'Send ID Table':

```
SIT = 
SUMMARIZE(
    'Clicks_Table';
    [ID];
    "OP";
    CONCATENATEX(
        CALCULATETABLE(
            VALUES('Clicks_Table'[Value])
        );
        [Value];    
        ","
    )
)
```

Comment: No thank you so much! I'll give this a try thank you again

Comment: It gives me the following error:
"The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar view."
Any idea why this is happening or how I could work around it?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply (Easter and such). It's difficult knowing what your problem is without seeing your code. So as a first steåp, can you send the code?